# Align text below input

Tags: css

I have a text-input with a list below.

I now want the list to start exactly under the input on the left side.

Here is a [jsFiddle.](http://goo.gl/vQZd0I)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#underbox li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 200px;" />
<ul id="underbox">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Next</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code here, and post your attempts to position the list where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your styles to:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
}
ul {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
#underbox li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**input** and **ul** => same width / 
**ul** => text-align: center; margin: 0 auto (for set position to center); padding: 0 (disable default style);
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7sm6rrx/10/)

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
#underbox {

    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

}
#underbox li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add style to the ul element like that: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/j6f8L7Lp/

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#underbox li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul#underbox {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 200px;" />
<ul id="underbox">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Next</li>
</ul>
```